# Shiny Correlation Plot

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to build a simple Shiny app, using USArrests database, that shows the correlation between density population and the 3 variables of crimes (Murder, Assault, Rape), changing the crime variables with selectInpuct.

Here the code of ui.R:

```
 shinyUI(fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Violent Crime Rates by US State"),

    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            helpText("A series of plots that display correlation between density population and various kind of crimes"),

            selectInput("var", 
                        label = "Choose a crime",
                        choices = c("Murder"=1, "Assault"=2,
                                       "Rape"=4),
                        selected = "Murder")


            ),

        mainPanel(plotOutput('crimeplot'))
    )
))
```

and the server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input,output){


output$crimeplot<- renderPlot({
    x<-as.numeric(input$var)
    y<-as.numeric(USArrests$UrbanPop)

    plot(x, y, log = "xy")




})
```

}

but running the app it returns:

ERROR: 'x' and 'y' lengths differ

Could you help me, and explain what's wrong with what I am doing?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fould a couple of small errors that I have fixed in the code below.

- Your selection returns the column number (as a string) and you need to convert it to a number and extract the relevant column from the data frame in `server.R`.
- The default value of `selected` in `ui.R` should be the starting value and not the label.

The updated `server.R` looks as follows

```
shinyServer(function(input,output){
                output$crimeplot<- renderPlot({
                    x<-as.numeric(USArrests[,as.numeric(input$var)])
                    y<-as.numeric(USArrests$UrbanPop)
                    plot(x, y, log = "xy", xlab=colnames(USArrests)[as.numeric(input$var)], ylab="Urban Pop")
                })
            })
```

and `ui.R` looks like this:

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Violent Crime Rates by US State"),    
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            helpText("A series of plots that display correlation between density population and various kind of crimes"),

            selectInput("var",
                        label = "Choose a crime",
                        choices = c("Murder"=1, "Assault"=2,
                            "Rape"=4),
                        selected = 1)
            ),

        mainPanel(plotOutput('crimeplot'))
        )
    ))
```

Comment: Dear ekstroem, it works! thank you very much for your help and for the explanation!